# Package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 133 pos 12: '_overlay != null':

Tags: dart, flutter

entry is a instance of  OverlayEntry class

```
entry?.remove();
```

Error

```
Package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 133 pos 12: '_overlay != null':
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Resolved**

> After lots of research a try I found below a simple solution.

```
entry?.remove();
entry = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this work for me

Answer (score 13):

If there is no OverlayEntry inserted to the Overlay and you try to call the remove method, you will get that error: `Failed assertion: '_overlay != null'`. So before removing the entry, add a condition to judge whether it is legal or not. It's more like a hack code, you can add a variable like `isEntryNotNull` for convenience and understandable as well. And when you insert a new OverlayEntry into Overlay, reassign it to the entry variable, then the condition will work fine.

```dart
if (entry != null) {
  entry.remove();
  entry = null;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding comments to explain how it works increase the long-term value of the answer.

Comment: Well, if there is no OverlayEntry inserted to the Overlay and you try to call the remove method, you will get that error: Failed assertion: '_overlay != null'. So before removing the entry, add a condition to judge whether it is legal or not. It's more like a hack code, you can add a variable like isEntryNotNull for convinience and understandable as well. And when you insert a new OverlayEntry into Overlay, reassign it to the `entry` variable, then the condition will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

try this, it is working for me

```
 if (overlayEntry != null && overlayEntry.mounted) {
  overlayEntry?.remove();
  overlayEntry = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the overlay is mounted like this

```
  if (floatingDropdown?.mounted ?? false) {
    floatingDropdown?.remove();
  }
```